# Protractor: How to locate elements on the second nested iframe

Tags: iframe, modal-dialog, protractor

Using Protractor for nonAngular page I am facing a problem with modal element location from an iframe, which is nested in another iframe. I'm trying to locate the element and I always get Element not found error.

Page source:

```
<iframe ...
    ...
    <iframe frameborder="0" ...
        <html
            <head
                <body
                    <div id="viewport" style= ...
                        <div id="modal" class=" unit ...
```

Page object:

```
this.layout = element(by.css('div[data-field="device"]'));
this.firstIframe = this.layout.element(by.tagName('iframe'));
this.content = element(by.tagName('body.desktop'));
this.secondIframe = element.all(by.tagName('iframe')).last();
this.modalUnit = element(by.id('modal'));
```

Spec:

```
...
// waiting for first iframe to be visible
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(page.firstIframe),10000).then(function() {

            // switch to first iframe
            browser.driver.switchTo().frame(page.firstIframe.getWebElement());

            // verify content is displayed
            expect(page.content.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();

            // switch to default content
            browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
        });

        // waiting for second iframe to be visible
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(page.secondIframe),10000).then(function() {

            // switch to second iframe
            browser.driver.switchTo().frame(page.secondIframe.getWebElement());

            // waiting for modal to be visible
            browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(page.modalUnit),10000).then(function() {
...
```

Content element is found in the first iframe without a problem. But modalUnit element from the second iframe is not found, whereas second iframe is found. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure you are in the context of the right frame when you search for "modal unit" element? Meaning, sure the `last()` would give you the frame you think you need?..

Comment: @alecxe: Yes, because if I search for all the iframe tagnames on the page I get a result of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heureka!!! Found simple solution to my problem (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/OkcX2vaZoek):

```
...
// waiting for first iframe to be visible
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(page.firstIframe),10000).then(function() {

            // switch to first iframe
            browser.driver.switchTo().frame(page.firstIframe.getWebElement());

            // verify content is displayed
            expect(page.content.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
        });

        // waiting for second iframe to be visible
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(page.secondIframe),10000).then(function() {

            // switch to second iframe
            browser.driver.switchTo().frame(page.secondIframe.getWebElement());

            // waiting for modal to be visible
            browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(page.modalUnit),10000).then(function() {
...
```

I had to remove `browser.switchTo().defaultContent();` before I switch to second iframe and all troubles were gone.